# Does Min Max algorithm leads to information loss?

Tags: machine-learning

Simplifying the question with an example.
Lets say I have a time series data and the variables are time, temperature, growth_of_microbe. Now I have observed usually with a higher high of temperature there is an effect on growth of microbe. Sample of the data is as follows

```
| Hour of Day(H) | Temp(T) | Microbe(P) | Min-Max of P(P#) | Why shouldn't P# be? |
|:--------------:|:-------:|:---------:|:----------------:|:-------------------:|
|        1       |    30   |     12    |   (12-1)/(23-1)  |                     
|
|        2       |    32   |     14    |   (14-1)/(23-1)  |   (14-12)/(14-12)   |
|        3       |    31   |     5     |   (5-1)/(23-1)   |     (5-5)/(14-5)    |
|        4       |    33   |     23    |   (23-1)/(23-1)  |    (23-5)/(14-5)    |
|        5       |    35   |     1     |   (1-1)/(23-1)   |     (1-1)/(23-1)    |
```

With respect to the above table, Min-Max uses the lowest/highest data  within the **total available time** rather than the lowest/highest **till the time the value is calculated** 

Doesn't this lead to information loss?